# How to get text data from google drive files?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to index my google drive data for that i need to get the text content from my google drive files. I am using List api to get the files and i am able to get the title and mimetype and all data but i am not able to get fulltext or content or text data from there by using this api. I am getting only the below stuff.

{ kind: 'drive#file',

```
   id: '0BwWXsHdw22TDMlJyTTZfbnM1cnFBTXdDWlFteEg1dFB3RFN3',
   etag: '"KYLl3b7q6n8KW2kbVvK9NFUdVkc/MTM5NDY4OTY1NDM0MA"',
   openWithLinks: [Object],
   iconLink: 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_word_list.png',
   thumbnailLink: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/iyq9t99atUoaWlf7N75mSalyoh5gvK6YAeDIx5iAqJZFtX4iMIouOI4VGySCqsEYFXC3f9v9aqSqUolS5IZ7YeQ=s220',
   title: 'OpenVPN Client Configuration on Ubuntu.docx',
   mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
   labels: [Object],
   createdDate: '2014-01-24T12:58:38.000Z',
   modifiedDate: '2014-03-13T05:47:34.340Z',
   modifiedByMeDate: '2014-03-13T05:47:34.340Z',
   lastViewedByMeDate: '2014-03-13T05:52:37.684Z',
   parents: [Object],
   userPermission: [Object],
   originalFilename: 'OpenVPN Client Configuration on Ubuntu.docx',
   fileExtension: 'docx',
   md5Checksum: 'ecd71a2b9315ed67299003dacda8c3f0',
   fileSize: '290094',
   quotaBytesUsed: '290094',
   ownerNames: [Object],
   owners: [Object],
   lastModifyingUserName: '******',
   lastModifyingUser: [Object],
   editable: true,
   copyable: true,
   writersCanShare: true,
   shared: false,
   appDataContents: false,
   headRevisionId: '0BwWXsHdw22TDV2RuWlpjWmZzRVp5ZTVSQUJSZ012Mkw4K0hVPQ' } ] }
```

And i tried .file api also but this one is also not working. Plz help me to resolve this.

And i want to do it with nodejs. How can i do this?

Comment: You should specify your environment (Java,.NET, PHP, ...) to get more specific help. I work on Android/Java, so the answer below is taken from there.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I don't see the *downloadUrl* field in your list above. You may [go here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) and play a little bit with 'try it' at the bottom, to get the request just right. In my java based code, I recall something like 2 step process:

1/ get the list

```
Drive  _svc;
FileList _gooLst = _svc.files().list().setMaxResults(MAX_DOWN).setQ(_rqst)
             .setFields("items(id,title,downloadUrl)").execute();

for (File f : _gooLst.getItems()){ 
  f.getId(); 
  f.getTitle(); 
  String foo = f.getDownloadUrl();
}
```

That's the 'list' request, notice that you should limit the fields in the list so you don't clog the pipeline

2/ get the contents from *downloadUrl*

```
    InputStream is = _svc.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(
                      new GenericUrl(foo)).execute().getContent();
```

and finally, parse the stream to get your ... whatever you need.

Comment: I want to do it with nodejs. How can i do this? i am using google- drive nodejs . plz check this code  in  link https://www.npmjs.org/package/google-drive.

Comment: haven't a clue (never been there) but the general idea should remain (tested by https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get ) 1/ you get URL from 'list'...   2/ you get contents from 'get' ...

Comment: If we have different type of file like .pdf, .doc then How to read this InputStream and get all text data from it?